# How Do I Get innerWidth in Internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript

In all recent browser:

```
 window.innerWidth // 1920
```

In Internet explorer 8

```
 window.innerWidth // undefined
```

What is the best way to get this value in IE8?

Comment: Have you explored [jQuery](http://jquery.com)? It's very easy to do this using it.

Comment: yes for sure, $(window).innerWidth() works fine also in IE8, thanks

Comment: @AntoJs `$(window).innerWidth()` does not return the same number as `window.innerWidth` if the vertical scroll bar is visible on the page.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The `innerWidth` is supported by IE9 not IE8, you can do this insteaad:

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
```

The above line will get you the width from IE as well as other standard-compliant browsers.

---

If you use jQuery, `$(window).innerWidth()` will give you desired result in all browsers too.

Comment: `$(window).innerWidth()` does not return the same number as `window.innerWidth` if the vertical scroll bar is visible on the page.

Comment: .innerWidth() is not applicable to window and document objects, as mentioned in jquery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/
"This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead."

Comment: I needed `document.body.clientWidth` even in IE9 (quirks)

Answer (score 5):

For getting this, I still use:

```
window.innerWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
window.innerHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

But to imitate the real dom-getter take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136089/1250044

Answer (score 4):

for ie8 use

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Answer (score 4):

I know that the `innerWidth` might not be quite the same, but [`getBoundingClientRect`](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/) could also be used in a similar capacity:

```
elem = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
width = elem.getBoundingClientRect().right - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

Comment: width = elem.getBoundingClientRect().right - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
- Uncaught TypeError: elem.getBoundingClientRect is not a function.
width = elem.right - elem.left;
- OK

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from IE 8 with

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Be advised that this value will not be exactly the same that IE 9 returns for `window.innerWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you can try this to get `height` and `width`

```
var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') { //Chrome
     myWidth = window.innerWidth; 
     myHeight = window.innerHeight;
} else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
     myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
     myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) { //IE9
     myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; 
     myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: The comment 'Chrome' is misleading as this property is supported by all modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerWidth?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.innerWidth#Browser_compatibility

... including IE9 which makes the 'else if' obsolete.

Comment: Have you read the question? OP has asked for code which will work for IE8

Comment: let me rephrase "...which makes the second 'else if' obsolete".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

this is used for ie8 to get the client width

Answer (score -1):

Please note: .innerWidth method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead.

[jquery api documentation for .innerwidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)