# Javascript: simply cannot get the actual width of the document (jsfiddle provided)

Tags: javascript

Edited:

I want to get the actual with of the document with JS.

I created a fiddle which I know is 1160px width,
this works in Google chrome, but not in IE:

```
document.body.clientWidth+document.body.scrollLeft
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W36FG/18/

(just scroll the fiddle and hover the div);

Any ideas?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410088/how-do-i-get-innerwidth-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight` in most browsers.

or for IE specific,

`document.documentElement.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetHeight`

or `document.documentElement.clientWidth`

as per your comment,

`window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth`
should work.

***and here's what you actually wanted*** (took us a while to get there, but hey, we got it)

`document.body.scrollWidth`

Comment: could you suggest some cross-browser solution? I just have no idea what to do with all these new properties you enlisted... ^.^

Comment: and if you're wondering why the result doesn't match the width you specified in css, it's because your css is getting overridden by jsfiddle, not because the size is wrong

Comment: hmmm, sec, I'll try it with the actual site then.

Comment: Are you sure your monitor can even display 1160? Or that the parent element is over 1160? If either of those is false, your element won't be 1160, despite what the css says

Comment: could also be the case if the css is being overridden by more specific css

Comment: I'm absolutely sure, because it's the width of my page, and it's working perfect.

Comment: Man that's impossible. I'm 100% sure that my HTML, BODY and what is inside of them are 1160px.

Comment: Well, not to be rude, but reopen the jsfiddle you made with my code, hit f12 (assuming youre using ie, chrome, or ff), hit the select element tool, and then hover over your div, looking for the dimensions. You'll find that that result and the result from my code is identical.

Comment: Well, regardless of who is right or wrong, this should help with your validation: http://www.mioplanet.com/products/pixelruler/

Comment: and here is a result showing 1260 as well: http://jsfiddle.net/W36FG/27/embedded/result/

Comment: Are you kidding? :) I just want to get the width of my document, why do I need any plugins? These coordinates are absolutely correct, and If I set these coordinates to a trailing object it would follow the mouse even if I scroll the document.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what I want. I want it to show 1160 always, no matter if it is resized, scrolled...

Comment: That is a ruler that shows up on your screen. It has nothing to do with your code, nor will it tell you an exact value of anything. It's just there so that people like you who don't believe people like me can get help understanding why they are wrong.

Comment: you want the monitor window size? Well thats a different scenario entirely, and your jsfiddle didn't match that at all. hang on

Comment: was gonna make a jsfiddle for you, but i can't remember my acct stuff. anyway, screen.width is what you're looking for

Comment: but I want to know the width of my actual content.... which is 1160 in my fiddle, I could have set it fixed, but other pages wary in width.

Comment: then what are you looking for? 1160, in your case, is what you're *trying* to set the document width as. Document width will change when the window is resized. So what exactly do you need?

Comment: the fiddle you posted does ***not***, in any way whatsoever, have any width anywhere matching 1160. I promise. If you look at the embedded result, it does. And on the embedded result, my code returns 1160

Comment: I want to know the width of my content, so that if when I add some absolute positioned object that they would not get outside of it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W36FG/27/embedded/result/ returns the what ever size I will resize the window to. It does not return the constant width

Comment: My code gives you that. You ***want*** it to change when resized. Because if you resize it to be smaller, you have a smaller area to work with, and thus you can only fit smaller abs positioned elements inside it.

Comment: Nope, as it is scrollable, and we would just have to scroll to see it

Comment: I don't **want** it to change.

Comment: @user1125062 that's because when you resize your window, your body ***becomes smaller***. If you set it to absolute, it won't, but if you set it to absolute my code will work, too

Comment: oh, well that would have helped. Try document.getElementById("yourElementID").scrollWidth

Comment: Yes, that's much more closer... :)))

Comment: @user1125062 Haha, sorry, it just wasn't clear what you were asking. But yeah, in your case, `document.body.scrollWidth` will work in pretty much all browsers (except IE version < 8)

Comment: @user1125062 No problem. I'll edit my answer and then would you mind accepting it/upvoting as you see fit? :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `width()` and `outerWidth()` functions

in your html file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

in your js file:

```
alert($("body").outerWidth());
```

Comment: what version of IE are you using? it works on my machine for IE 8.0

Comment: I'm using IE9, but it show like 300-400 px instead of 1160 expected