# Jquery IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
jQuery(window).resize(function() {

var zoomNew = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
    if (zoom != zoomNew) {
    alert('key is down');
    jQuery(".left_body").width((window.innerWidth-984)/2-6+"px");
    jQuery(".right_body").width((window.innerWidth-984)/2-6+"px");
    }
});
```

Not working in IE

Comment: What is it doing? Any error messages?

Comment: wat you mean by not working? is it giving any output?

Comment: How is zoom ever not equal to zoomNew!?

Comment: Its not working in IE.Its not giving output and alert message in IE

Comment: should explain what you are trying to do in full

Comment: zoom new is not equal to zoom when inner width changes

Comment: I am trying to do when i zoom the browser window than the .left_body and .right_body css change acc. to window inner width.its working in chrome and firefox but not in IE

Comment: @gaurav See my answer & mithunsatheesh's answer.

Comment: I am not understanding why people are disliking my question?

Comment: @gaurav http://stackoverflow.com/faq should tell you the reasons for dislike.

Answer (score 0):

*"window.innerHeight/Width
Provided by most browsers, but not Internet Explorer 8-, and even in Internet Explorer 9+, it is not available in quirks mode."*

References:

- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow
- [How Do I Get innerWidth in Internet explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410088/how-do-i-get-innerwidth-in-internet-explorer-8)

..so you will have to find a different method that is supported cross-browser. In the stackoverflow link I've posted, Sarfraz's accepted answer gives you the change you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

it is because

```
window.innerWidth
```

is returning undefined in IE. Resulting in the zoom value to be **NaN**

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: use jquery to find **$(window).innerWidth()**